# Usage of TICKET THERE AND BACK

Tags: usage

Aside from the other ways of referring to a round-trip ticket, ¿is there anything wrong with saying "I bought a plane ticket there and back." To me it sounds perfectly natural and I've found it in several books by reputable authors. However, an American native speaker is telling me that it's unnatural.

[Here](https://www.google.com/search?ei=JGCuWsCYLIbWzgK44YHYDQ&q=%22plane%20ticket%20there%20and%20back%22&oq=%22plane%20ticket%20there%20and%20back%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i30k1.5117.8180.0.8492.2.2.0.0.0.0.107.162.1j1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.161....0.eDPQtJvLW3M) are several instances of it on Google.

Comment: Perfectly natural but unconventional.  **there and back** when referring to the two legs of a trip is normally used in contexts where you're describing the journey, not buying tickets. *We drove there and back in only five hours.*

Comment: I thought tenebris gave you a pretty decent answer there. It's a shame (but not a cryin shame)  it was deleted. And what is this with the quasi-Spanish-style question-mark anyway?? :)

Comment: I use it to avoid adding a question mark at the end after something that isn't a question.

Comment: Interesting   Maybe it will catch on.

Comment: hahahaha, I doubt it. To me it makes perfect sense.

Comment: In my AmE it would be "I bought a plane ticket *to* there and back."

Comment: @user3169: I betcha your micropauses are *plane-ticket ... to there .. and back* whereas without the preposition it's *there-and-back*.

Answer (score 2):

It is not unnatural in British English, in which round-trip ticket is not common but the more usual BrE term would be a return ticket. "There and back" is a direct translation of the German "hin und zürück" and maybe that is where it came from.

Comment: German actually does have [a specific word for a round-trip/return ticket](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/german-english/r%C3%BCckfahrkarte). So the construction with "hin und zurück" is only marginally less "standard" than "there and back" in English, and only due to the fact that "Rückfahrkarte" _can_ be understood as really only a _return_ ticket (that is, a ticket "back", and not "there").

Comment: That potential confusion exists in English too - our "return **fares**" usually obtain two physical **tickets** marked **`OUT`** and **`RTN`**.

Comment: See also ***on the return trip*** or ***... journey***.